# Getting The Period in Special Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I try to define Sql function to return the format DAY:HOUR:MINUTE from integer input (seconds).

How should be the internal query for that?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is the integer input?  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: 5000 returns 1:23:20

Comment: You must mean HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS.

Comment: The math is easy: `seconds / 3600`, `seconds / 60 % 60`, `seconds % 60`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This could be a long code but it works I believe**

```
DECLARE @INPUT AS INT = 5000
DECLARE @HOUR AS INT
DECLARE @MINUTE AS INT
DECLARE @SEC AS INT

SET @HOUR = @INPUT / (60 * 60)
SET @INPUT = @INPUT - (@HOUR * 60 * 60)
SET @MINUTE = @INPUT / 60
SET @INPUT = @INPUT - (@MINUTE * 60)
SET @SEC = @INPUT

SELECT cast(@HOUR AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ':' + replace(str(@MINUTE, 2, 0) + ':' + str(@SEC, 2, 0), ' ', '0')
```

**UPDATE**

Just noticed you include the **day in the result** as well, so if the day is needed the query should be:

```
DECLARE @INPUT AS INT = 432010
DECLARE @DAY AS INT
DECLARE @HOUR AS INT
DECLARE @MINUTE AS INT
DECLARE @SEC AS INT

SET @DAY = @INPUT / (24 * 60 * 60)
SET @INPUT = @INPUT - (@DAY * 24 * 60 * 60)
SET @HOUR = @INPUT / (60 * 60)
SET @INPUT = @INPUT - (@HOUR * 60 * 60)
SET @MINUTE = @INPUT / 60
SET @INPUT = @INPUT - (@MINUTE * 60)
SET @SEC = @INPUT

SELECT CAST(@DAY AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ':' + REPLACE(STR(@HOUR, 2, 0) + ':' + STR(@MINUTE, 2, 0) + ':' + STR(@SEC, 2, 0), ' ', '0')
```

this is returning `5:00:00:10` as an example, meaning `Five days and 10 seconds`

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you would write:

```
time '00:00:00' + 5000 * interval '1 second'
```

You can see this in action [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=17d1b0ba9ec41e83fe157bdc503735fa).

However, not all databases support this functionality.  And date/time functions are notoriously database-dependent.

In SQL Server, you can use:

```
select convert(time, dateadd(second, 5000, 0))
```

Comment: This should work in 2008R2. What error do you get when you execute this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (5000)
,(95000)

Select left(SomeCol/86400,3)
       +':'
       +left(convert(time,DATEADD(second,SomeCol,0)),8)
  From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
(No column name)
0:01:23:20
1:02:23:20
```